# Timezone without seconds in javascript / selenium ide

Tags: javascript, selenium, time, seconds

I want to grab the time from a different time zone without the having the seconds.

This is what I am using:

```
javascript{var d = new Date(); d.setTime(new Date( (d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) ) + (3600000 * (+10) ) )); d.toLocaleTimeString();}
```

The results generates i.e. 8:32:51 AM

How I would like it to generate: 8:32 AM

Comment: Don't be "that guy"... google it. You know this has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it will be done.

```
var d = new Date(); 

d.setTime(new Date( (d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) ) + (3600000 * (+10) ) ));

d.toLocaleTimeString([], {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```